# Please Help me with Archive 404 Pagination

Tags: pagination, 404-error

When I click on page 2, there is a 404 page.

How could i fix it ?

This is my pagination on `archive.php`

```
<?php

global $query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
    'before_page_number' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">'.$translated.' </span>'
) );

?>
```

Comment: Are you putting a call to `query_posts` at the top of your archive template?

Answer (score 0):

Your only real reason to try and use `paginate_links()` seems to be your custom `'before_page_number'` argument.

Ditch your code and use `the_posts_pagination();` instead, pass it only the `'before_page_number'` argument in an array.